# AMPscript - extract certain information from a payload to display it on the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm developing an email with a specific bloc that will send a payload with speicifc infomration about a product : SKU, name, URL, Image_URL :

Here is what i receive from the payload :

---

```
{categories:SHOES,

images:https:\/\/uk.test.com\/images\/is\/image\/lv\/1\/PP_VP_L\/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg,language:en-gb,id:1A8NMT,views:6,views_ip:6,currency:gbp,product_id:1A8NMT,sku_code:1A8NMT,
name:Stellar Trainers,description:Discover Shoes Stellar Trainers
A colourful pattern on lightweight, technical fabric brings a fresh, summery feel to this seasonal version of Shoes's emblematic Stellar Trainers. Refined details, such as a white calf leather trim and gold-tone eyelets, elevate this classic design, which is finished with a toe cap in leather and an outsole.\u00a0 <\/p>,unit_sale_price:720.0,unit_sale_base_price:972.23,base_currency:USD,unit_price:720.0,unit_base_price:972.23,
url:https:\/\/uk.test.com\/eng-gb\/products\/stellar-trainers-nvprod2550142v#1A8NMT,size:36.0,gender:women,
image_url:https:\/\/uk.test.com\/images\/is\/image\/lv\/1\/PP_VP_L\/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg,
locale:en-gb-gbp,macro_family:SHOES,family:SNEAKER,sub_family:SNEAKER,product_gender:Women,status_buy_online:true,macro_function:SHOES,function:SNEAKER,macro_color:MAINCOLORZ06,status_visible_online:true,macro_color_name:Black,in_stock:true,interest_category:Women_Shoes,locate_in_store:true,is_searchable:true,category:SHOES}},{id:1A8NLF,weight:0.76,strategy:visually_similar_v3,
```

I would like specifically to extract only the Image_URL, URL and name but i dont know how it can be done throught AMPscript.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What you are showing is not a valid JSON. Without it being valid, you will have difficulty extracting information from it.

Comment: Hello, What do you mean by valid JSON ? Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Good example of formatter/validator (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) and good intro to what a JSON is (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Answer (score 2):

AMPScript does not natively have a way to parse a JSON, so you will need to use GTL or SSJS.

Once you make that a valid JSON, you can use GTL (Guide Template Language) to iterate through it to get the info you need. Like so:

```js
%%[
  SET @json = { "categories": "SHOES", "images": "https://uk.test.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg", "language": "en-gb", "id": "1A8NMT", "views": 6, "views_ip": 6, "currency": "gbp", "product_id": "1A8NMT", "sku_code": "1A8NMT", "name": "Stellar Trainers", "description": "Discover Shoes Stellar Trainers A colourful pattern on lightweight, technical fabric brings a fresh, summery feel to this seasonal version of Shoes's emblematic Stellar Trainers. Refined details, such as a white calf leather trim and gold-tone eyelets, elevate this classic design, which is finished with a toe cap in leather and an outsole. /p>", "unit_sale_price": "720.0", "unit_sale_base_price": "972.23", "base_currency": "USD", "unit_price": "720.0", "unit_base_price": "972.23", "url": "https://uk.test.com/eng-gb/products/stellar-trainers-nvprod2550142v#1A8NMT", "size": "36.0", "gender": "women", "image_url": "https://uk.test.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg", "locale": "en-gb-gbp", "macro_family": "SHOES", "family": "SNEAKER", "sub_family": "SNEAKER", "product_gender": "Women", "status_buy_online": "true", "macro_function": "SHOES", "function": "SNEAKER", "macro_color": "MAINCOLORZ06", "status_visible_online": "true", "macro_color_name": "Black", "in_stock": "true", "interest_category": "Women_Shoes", "locate_in_store": "true", "is_searchable": "true", "category": "SHOES"}
]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows=20}}
  {{.data}}
    {{ "target" : "@json" }}
  {{/data}}
  SKU: {{sku_code}}
  Name: {{name}}
  URL: {{url}}
  Image_URL: {{image_url}}
{{/datasource}}
```

or you can utilize SSJS to do this, like so:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var json = {
  "categories": "SHOES",
  "images": "https://uk.test.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg",
  "language": "en-gb",
  "id": "1A8NMT",
  "views": 6,
  "views_ip": 6,
  "currency": "gbp",
  "product_id": "1A8NMT",
  "sku_code": "1A8NMT",
  "name": "Stellar Trainers",
  "description": "Discover Shoes Stellar Trainers A colourful pattern on lightweight, technical fabric brings a fresh, summery feel to this seasonal version of Shoes's emblematic Stellar Trainers. Refined details, such as a white calf leather trim and gold-tone eyelets, elevate this classic design, which is finished with a toe cap in leather and an outsole. /p>",
  "unit_sale_price": "720.0",
  "unit_sale_base_price": "972.23",
  "base_currency": "USD",
  "unit_price": "720.0",
  "unit_base_price": "972.23",
  "url": "https://uk.test.com/eng-gb/products/stellar-trainers-nvprod2550142v#1A8NMT",
  "size": "36.0",
  "gender": "women",
  "image_url": "https://uk.test.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test--AK2U4ATX02_PM2_Front view.jpg",
  "locale": "en-gb-gbp",
  "macro_family": "SHOES",
  "family": "SNEAKER",
  "sub_family": "SNEAKER",
  "product_gender": "Women",
  "status_buy_online": "true",
  "macro_function": "SHOES",
  "function": "SNEAKER",
  "macro_color": "MAINCOLORZ06",
  "status_visible_online": "true",
  "macro_color_name": "Black",
  "in_stock": "true",
  "interest_category": "Women_Shoes",
  "locate_in_store": "true",
  "is_searchable": "true",
  "category": "SHOES"
}

Write('SKU: ' + json["sku_code"] + '<br>')
Write('Name: ' + json["name"] + '<br>')
Write('URL: ' + json["url"] + '<br>')
Write('Image_URL: ' + json["image_url"] + '<br>')

</script>
```